# Low fps in low computation java paintcomponent

Tags: java, performance, graphics2d, paintcomponent

I am making a game where for the purpose of this question i have a a class that extends JFrame that adds a class that extends JPanel(GamePanel). in GamePanel i have a run method that has two functions update(); and repaint(); and then a Thread.sleep(20). The update function takes about 1-2ms. I have all my drawing stuff in paintComponent(Graphics g) which seems to correctly get called when i use repaint() since stuff shows up on screen.

My problem is that it is increeedibly laggy. When i didn't have Thread.sleep(20) it was unplayable with like 2fps. I read that this was because repaint() wasnt given enough time to finish or something so i added a delay before next loop. anything above or under 20ms seems to make it more laggy.

I've tried using graphics configuration stuff, double buffering and more but it stays laggy. On my home pc, which is an intel i5, quad core, 3.2GHz i'm only getting around 100fps, and on a school computer i get around 15fps (ok pc, like amd dual core i believe). The paintComponent loop is Super lightweight! just drawmap with offset depending on player position, then draw player in middle of screen! I am using a map that is 2000x2000, 0.8mb. Tried switching to 1000x1000 0.4mb and no difference.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    //Rendering settings and stuff
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    //Draw map     gameMap.gameMap is a bufferedImage
    g2d.drawImage(gameMap.gameMap, gameMap.x, gameMap.y, null);
    //Draw health bar
    g2d.setColor(healthBarColor);
    g2d.setComposite(alphaHealthBarBackground);
    g2d.fillRect(100, 19, 200, 23);
    g2d.setFont(font);
    g2d.setComposite(alphaNormal);
    g2d.setColor(healthBarColor);
    g2d.drawString("HP: ", 20, 40);
    g2d.fillRect(100, 19, player.health * 2, 23);

    //Draw player      player.playerImage is a BufferedImage
    rotatePlayer.setToRotation(rotation, rotationAnchor.x, rotationAnchor.y);
    rotatePlayer.translate(xResolution / 2, yResolution / 2);
    g2d.drawImage(player.playerImage, rotatePlayer, this);
    g2d.setColor(Color.white);
}
```

This results in 100fps on relatively awesome computer and 15fps on descent computer!

Comment: Exactly how big is the `this` being painted?  *"15fps on descent computer!"*  If it is descending into Hades that would be understandable, since 'it's going to Hell'.  ;)

Comment: Well if i'm understanding you right then the "this" being painted is as big as the screen size. The application is fullscreen. I use toolkit to get screen size so at home it is 1920x1080 and at school the screen is 1280x1024 i believe...

Haha, decent ;) funny joke...:P

Comment: Note:  1) Best to do FPS tests at a fixed rendering size.  2) You can edit the question to change the spelling.  So could I, but I'll leave it to your discretion.  :)

Answer (score 4):

Not pretending to be ultimate solution, just some tips:

1. Make sure your buffered images are have same color model as default of `GraphicsDevice` on which they drawn. The method [`GraphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html#createCompatibleImage%28int,%20int%29) could create such images.
2. If it is possible, try to split whole huge map to tiles and skip rendering off-screen (out of game view) parts.
3. It seems you use passive rendering, as you mentioned calling of `repaint()`. Event Dispatch Thread used for many things in Swing and AWT, and it can't guarantee acceptable timing for actively rendered games. Maybe it worth to redesign rendering part of game to use Active Rendering. Tutorial and example can be found [here](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/java-games-active-rendering-r2418).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
1. I actually changed all BufferedImage to Image. gave +10 fps. Don't quite understand what you meant there, the code for reading in the Image is:   gameMap = ImageIO.read(new File(GM));//GM=String 
How does  GraphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleImage fit there?

2. Made it scale all funny. No fps gain

3. A pain XD but it gave me the idea of g2d.setClip(0,0,screenx,screeny). Gave +50fps. Up at 160fps! :)

4. Gonna try that now :D

Thanks!!

Comment: I meant that images read by ImageIO may require some conversion when drawn on target surface. In example, As I remember, on Windows platform best performance achieved with images defined in [`BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_INT_ARGB). You would load images trough `ImageIO.read`, create same-sized images trough GraphicsConfiguration and then render every source images on "compatible" one. And use the result in game rendering.

Comment: And yes, I pointed to wrong paint overload by mistake. Actually, I meant [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) version, which intended to draw portion of image.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for game development I donot think drawing a huge image in a Swing paintComponent is ever going to win any speed records.  100 FPS is still amazing (and about 40 FPS more than the refresh rate of most LCD displays).

For more speed it is essential that the drawing primitives you are using are accelerated.  On your school PC's they may simply lack a decent graphics card that provides the 2D acceleration needed (how do these PC's feel doing normal 2D operations in say browsers and paint programs?)

You may want to look into a framework that uses OpenGL instead, like JOGL.  Another option is to try out JavaFX 2 -- it may have a better rendering pipeline.

Comment: Interesting. I believe my schools computers have ok graphics cards. We have from time to time played CS1.6 on them without any lag whatsoever. You can play HD video on them and play flash games and stuff. I was thinking more in the lines of multithreading. My game uses threads for music, collision detection, movement, shots being fired, sending out UDP information for multiplayer etc. About the acceleration. Is Graphics2D by default hardware accelerated? I will check out jogl and javafx2...

Answer (score 0):

I am also developing a Java game and have done many things the same as you (extending JPanel and calling repaint()). One difference is that I am using a javax.swing.Timer to call an ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) method to update my game every 5ms. At the end of the method it calls repaint() to do the rendering.

Also if you are using Graphics2D to do your rendering you can use RenderingHints to guide the computer on how you want your game to be rendered (Eg, speed or quality, stuff like that).

I haven't measured the FPS exactly but I get no lag on my Ubuntu 12.10 system and JUST a bit slower on Windows 8.

I apologize if my response isn't exactly what you wanted but this is what has worked for me so far without problems.